# How to run Add-In Command

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm trying to create an Add-In Command that will run in Word Online. I think I'm having trouble because the Microsoft documentation is not up to date.

I'm using these 2 articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands

In the yeoman generator, I selected React Addin and Word.

The current version of the yeoman generator creates a manifest.xml that already contains the `<VersionOverrides>` information, `commands` and `taskpane` folders (The documentation says VersionOverrides must be manually added).

I think all I need to do to call the generated Add-In Command code is replace the Taskpane action in the manifest with:

```
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
</Action>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: See if this learning article meets your needs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/office-add-ins-excel/5-exercise-worksheets-commands?ns-enrollment-type=LearningPath&ns-enrollment-id=learn-m365.m365-office-add-in-associate. Scroll down to the section **Configure the manifest to add a second ribbon button**. For the out-of-date create-addin-commands article, scroll to the bottom of that article and use the Feedback tool to create an issue. It will be assigned to a Microsoft writer to fix.